# How does the offset for a topic work in Kafka (Kafka_net)

Tags: c#, kafka-consumer-api

I have a basic producer app and a consumer app. if I run both and have both start consuming on their respective topics, I have a great working system. My thought was that if I started the producer and sent a message that I would be able to then start the consumer and have it pick up that message. I was wrong.

Unless both are up and running, I lose messages (or they do not get consumed).

my consumer app looks like this for comsuming...

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9092");

KafkaOptions options = new KafkaOptions(uri);                
BrokerRouter brokerRouter = new BrokerRouter(options);
Consumer consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(receiveTopic, brokerRouter));
```

---

```
List<OffsetResponse> offset = consumer.GetTopicOffsetAsync(receiveTopic, 100000).Result;

IEnumerable<OffsetPosition> t = from x in offset select new OffsetPosition(x.PartitionId, x.Offsets.Max());
consumer.SetOffsetPosition(t.ToArray());
IEnumerable<KafkaNet.Protocol.Message> msgs = consumer.Consume();
```

---

```
foreach (KafkaNet.Protocol.Message msg in msgs)
{
    do some stuff here based on the message received
}
```

unless I have the code between the lines, it starts at the beginning every time I start the application.
What is the proper way to manage topic offsets so messages are consumed after a disconnect happens?

If I run

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic chat-message-reply-XXX consumer-property fetch-size=40000000 --from-beginning
```

I can see the messages, but when I connect my application to that topic, the consumer.Consume() does not pick up the messages it has not already seen. I have tried this with and without runing the above bat file to see if that makes any difference. When I look at the consumer.SetOffsetPosition(t.ToArray()) call (t specifically) it shows that the offset is the count of all messages for the topic.

Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over to use Confluent's C# .NET package and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Set `auto.offset.reset` configuration in your `ConsumerOptions` to `earliest`. When the consumer group starts the consume messages, it will consume from the latest offset because the default value for `auto.offset.reset` is latest.

But I looked at *kafka-net* API now, it does not have a `AutoOffsetReset` property, and it seems pretty insufficient with its configuration in consumers. It also lacks documentation with method summaries.

I would suggest you use *Confluent .NET Kafka* Nuget package because it is owned by *Confluent* itself.

Also, why are calling `GetTopicOffsets` and setting that offset back again in consumer. I think when you configure your consumer, you should just start reading messages with `Consume()`.

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9092");

    var kafkaOptions = new KafkaOptions(uri);                
    var brokerRouter = new BrokerRouter(kafkaOptions);
    var consumerOptions = new ConsumerOptions(receivedTopic, brokerRouter);
    var consumer = new Consumer(consumerOptions);

    foreach (var msg in consumer.Consume())
    {
        var value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Value);

        // Process value here
    }
}
```

In addition, enable logs in your `KafkaOptions` and `ConsumerOptions`, they will help you a lot:

```
var kafkaOptions = new KafkaOptions(uri)
            {
                Log = new ConsoleLog()
            };
var consumerOptions = new ConsumerOptions(topic, brokerRouter)
            {
                Log = new ConsoleLog()
            });
```

Comment: When I do this, I end up getting every message ever sent to the topic from the beginning. Your code above was what I went with initially.